# Vagrant docker shellinit?

Tags: docker, vagrant, boot2docker

You know how when using boot2docker you can just call `$(boot2docker shellinit)` in your shell to load the proper environment? Then you can use normal `docker` commands in your terminal.

Is there a way to do that with the Vagrant docker provider, so you can easily communicate with Vagrant's Docker server?

Or, alternatively, pass `$(boot2docker shellinit)` into Vagrant so it uses your currently running Docker server, rather than starting its own?

Thanks.